# installation ubuntu subiquity wo snaps and wo firefox ? with ubuntu-desktop

Tags: 22.04, firefox, snap, subiquity

For the last 4 days, our Ubuntu installations via subiquity have been interrupted due to a package that absolutely wants to go online:
This package: ubuntu-desktop (ubuntu-desktop-minimal)

The installations are done in subiquity mode with an internal repository, and the Ubuntu machines do not have access to the internet.

It's impossible to install, and if I don't have this package, the installation crashes.
It's impossible to find the solution to install Ubuntu via subiquity without snaps, without Firefox before the "packages:" step of the user-data.
Five days ago everything was OK.